# How can I set (dtype=object) numpy array values to Python lists, without numpy interpreting the lists as lists of values?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of dtype=object, where the values are either Python lists, or `np.nan`.

I'd like to replace the values that are `np.nan` with [None] (not None).

For a pure Python list, I can already do this with `[ x if (x is not np.nan) else [None] for x in s ]`, and converting the array to a list is fine for my purpose, but out of curiosity, I wonder how this can be done with a numpy array. The difficulty is that, when using indexing, numpy tries to interpret any list as a list of values, rather than as the actual value I want to assign.

If I wanted to replace the values with `2`, for example, that is easy (normal np, pd imports; as an aside, np.isnan will not work in this instance, a weakness with the choice of float NaN for generic missing values in pandas, so I use pd.isnull, as this is for an issue with pandas internals anyway):

```
In [53]: s
Out[53]:
array([['asdf', 'asdf'], ['asdf'], nan, ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf'],
       ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']], dtype=object)

In [55]: s[pd.isnull(s)] = 2

In [56]: s
Out[56]:
array([['asdf', 'asdf'], ['asdf'], 2, ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf'],
       ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']], dtype=object)
```

Yet trying to replace them with [None] instead replaces them with None:

```
In [58]: s
Out[58]:
array([['asdf', 'asdf'], ['asdf'], nan, ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf'],
       ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']], dtype=object)

In [59]: s[pd.isnull(s)] = [None]

In [60]: s
Out[60]:
array([['asdf', 'asdf'], ['asdf'], None, ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf'],
       ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']], dtype=object)
```

This is, obviously, the behavior that one wants 99% of the time. It just so happens that this time, I want to assign the list as an object. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You could always explicitly wrap the list up as a scalar array of one object that happens to be a list, the same way you wrapped up `s` itself. But that's horribly ugly; hopefully someone has a better answer…

Comment: If _all_ of your elements were `list`s, you could just mutate the list in place (with `[:] = …`), but sadly that's not going to help here, because you obviously can't mutate `nan` in place into `[None]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that `s[…] = [None]` attempts to replace the array slice with the sequence of one value, `None`. What you actually want is to replace the slice with the sequence of one value, `[None]`, which you'd write as `[[None]]`.

However, that won't actually solve your problem; that just gets you to the problem you were trying to ask in the first place.

What you need to have is explicitly an *array* of 1 `object` element that happens to be the list `[None]`. For example:

```
>>> n = np.array([[None], 0], dtype=object)[:1]
>>> s[pd.isnull(s)] = n
```

Or, of course:

```
>>> n = np.empty((1,), dtype=object)
>>> n[0] = [None]
>>> s[pd.isnull(s)] = n
```

I'm 90% sure there's a more concise and readable way to create a 1-element array that's guaranteed to have the value `[None]`, and 80% sure there's a simpler way to do the whole thing in the first place, so hopefully someone will come up with a better answer… but if not, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `numpy.argmin()` since it return the position of `nan` and than replace them by `[None]` this way:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def to_none(array_):
    for i in range(array_[pd.isnull(array_)].size):
        array_[np.argmin(array_)] = [None]
    return array_


a = np.array([['asdf', 'asdf'], ['asdf'], np.nan, ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf'],np.nan,
       ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']], dtype=object)
a = to_none(a)

print a

>>
[['asdf', 'asdf'] ['asdf'] [None] ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf'] [None]
 ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']]

print a.dtype

>>
object
```